# Function with different arguments

Tags: python, function, arguments

I am writing a function and it should be able to take different arguments in one time. How can I define this arguments of the function?

```
def function('005=5=0002555')
def function('00025:001:002325', '/')
def function(date='05-0004-002294', separator='/')
def function(separator='*', date='0008=006=2001')
def function('21 12 2012', separator='+')
```

Comment: Depending on the version of python have a look at [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions)

Comment: This is a special case because sometimes for the same argument they are default arguments ('00025:001:002325', '/') and sometimes they have a keyword (date='05-0004-002294', separator='/') or even switch places (separator='*', date='0008=006=2001'). Anyone experience with this?

Comment: Sounds like just normal kwargs to me...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `*args` and `**kwargs`:

```
def function(*args, **kwargs):
   args1 = args if args else None
   args2 = [kwargs.get(i) for i in ['date', 'separator']]
```

Comment: how can you than access the arguments?  For example with:                           if date is None: 
        s = expired(args) + 1856305
        
    if date is not None:
        s = expired('date') + 1856305